# .htaccess remove index.php and hide parameter key from URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have the following URL

```
www.example.com/index.php?tag= xxx
```

I want to make it like the following using .htaccess

```
www.example.com/xxx
```

I done it with this code:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

SO if I input this URL:

```
www.example.com/index.php?tag=1000
```

it be redirect to:

```
www.example.com/?tag=1000
```

---

if: `www.example.com/1000` it works!

So I have dublicate URL and it's not good for seo.

How can redirect `www.example.com/index.php?tag=1000` to `www.example.com/1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can redirect `www.example.com/index.php?tag=1000` to `www.example.com/1000`

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?tag=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: we can't access the tag using $_GET['get'] anymore, how to solve this?

Comment: OP's existing internal rewrite rule has target of `index.php?tag=$1` that will get you `$_GET['get']`

Answer (score 1):

use this code for
.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

you index.php code will be

```
<?php 
echo $_REQUEST['key'];  
?>
```

then call
http://sitename.com/1000

output will be :1000