# How to remove index.php and hide parameter lang from url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following URL

```
http://localhost/apps/site/index.php?lang=es
```

I want to make it like the following using .htaccess

```
http://localhost/apps/site/es
```

#### .htaccess rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

When I try this url `http://localhost/apps/site/es` 
directly redirects me to `http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/`

I have tried this solution but not works for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30153794/7705186

Comment: Can you show us how you wrote your rewrite condition rule?

Comment: @catcon check my question please i have added my htaccess rules.

Comment: **When i try this url http://localhost/apps/site/es directly redirects me to http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/**, why do i feel you had another rewrite somewhere else and it run before yours..

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/apps/site/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(\w+)
RewriteRule apps/site/index.php /apps/site/%1 [QSD,L]
```

- First condition is to tell the module to apply the rule only if the request URI exactly `/apps/site/index.php`
- second condition if the first query parameter name is `lang` and it's value is a word. The `()` is to capture the value of the parameter and save it in `%1`
- In the rule we tell the module to remove `apps/site/index.php` and rewrite it by `/apps/site/%1` while replacing `%1` with the value we captured from the second condition
- `QSD` Query String Discard flag is to make the module not append the query to the final url (you must set it before `L` flag , this will **not** work `[L,QSD]`)

Now if you requested

```
http://localhost/apps/site/index.php?lang=es
```

it will be rewritten to

```
http://localhost/apps/site/es
```

you can test and play with rewrite rules on this site https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this solution is not work for me.

Comment: When you request `http://localhost/apps/site/index.php?lang=es` what URL is rewritten ?

Comment: Nothing, still the same url (http://localhost/apps/site/index.php?lang=es)

Comment: I have tried this solution and it's work:RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127.0.0.1/apps/site
RewriteRule (.*) http://127.0.0.1/apps/site/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*healthCheck=true.*
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1

Comment: Does it rewrite this `http://localhost/apps/site/index.php?lang=es` to this `http://localhost/apps/site/es` ?